Happy New Year!
I hope you had/will have a great party when the date line comes to your latitudes!
I'm sure, we'll see amazing advances in Cryptocurrencies in 2015, and Bitcoin.SE will be the place to ask and answer the questions about them.
Happy new year and all the best for 2015!
Murch
